# XFCE Panel covering status bar

Tags: unity, xubuntu, xfce

I have been using Unity for a while now and wanted to switch up to XFCE.

Commands used.

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

This has installed Xubuntu for me. Logged in and noticed an issue right off the bat. I have 3 screens in total, 2 next to each other, and one below.
If I open Chrome or any other browser the panel sits on top, so I then can't access minimize, close etc.

This occurs on all of the screens.

Any ideas?

Comment: Rightclick your panel , chose panel - panel preferences     then check the autohide and select alvays from the drop down meny. Now the panel is hidden until the mouse touches the border!

Answer (score 1):

Right-click the panel, then choose `Panel -> Panel Preferences`> and uncheck `don't reserve space on borders` in the `Display-tab`.